# Alternatives for expression "is that"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, sentence, clauses

For example,

> The key benefit of using A is that you can make even more money.
>
> The problem is that you have to do it by yourself.

Are there any better alternatives for expressing `is that`? I'm using `is that` clause too many times in a paper, and starting to be sick, to be honest.

Comment: You can elide "that", because it's permitted grammatically. Some form of "be" is listed as the second most frequent word after "the" by Oxford English Corpus and Corpus of Contemporary American English, so it's not your fault entirely. Try to pick another verb. Your first example is open to taking a larger diversity of verbs, but how do you say what a problem "is" without using "is"? It's a bit harder and you can still do it, but what you have is probably the simplest and most understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly other expressions though you may need to alter the sentence: e.g.
[**entails**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/entails?s=t)

> to cause or involve by necessity or as a consequence: a loss entailing
>   no regret.

They key benefit of using A **entails** the possibility of you making [or: the potential for you to make] more money.

Synonyms: **involves** (although somewhat weaker as it would only be part of the key benefit in your example) or simply **is** (... is the potential for you to make more money)

For your second sentence, depending on the precise context you might just write:

> **But** [or *however* or *unfortunately*] you have to do it by yourself.

An alternative might be to add a clause onto a previous sentence:..., **the drawback being** you have to do it yourself.

Comment: 'Involves' and 'is' are usually very different. 'Success in the restaurant business involves a large initial investment of money' means that such investment is **one** necessary factor.

Comment: *entails* means *has the consequence of*; it suggests that the money is an indirect result of the unspecified key benefit.

Comment: @Anton Sherwood. It's actually more direct and causal since it has the *necessary* consequence of making money.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. I think you're right. I've edited.